# Interacting with Ghostscript at a per page level

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I have a requirement to convert PDF files to Postscript, passing in different pre-determined `setpagedevice` parameters or plexing options for each page.

For example the parameters I would like to set may be:

`<</MediaPosition 1>> setpagedevice`
and
`<</MediaPosition 2>> setpagedevice`
for printer tray selection.
At the point of conversion, I know which MediaPosition I would like to set for each page in the file.

Each PDF file may have up to 5000 pages. Because of the high number of pages, I would like to interact with ghostscript at a per-page level to set each `setpagedevice` parameter.

At the moment, I am able to apply a `setpagedevice`, but of course this will set the same option for every page in the generated Postscript.

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=output.ps -c "<</MediaPosition 2>> setpagedevice" -f file1.pdf
```

Is this possible to achieve with ghostscript?

Comment: Thanks for the link above, however this shows how to process a whole file, or a subset of pages, but not interacting with every processed page.

Comment: You can either write a BeginPage procedure which will be called for every page, or you may be able to use the PSPageOptions parameter which is described in the documentation https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm#PS. Since 5000 page will result in a large array, you would almost certainly also need to put the command line parameters in a file, see the '@file' syntax here https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.54.0/Use.htm#General_switches. IMO, in general, you will want to use the PSDocOptions and PSPageOptions since those are passed through, setpagedevice parameters may not be.

Comment: That does sound inefficient! Where can I get started with writing handler.ps?

Comment: Thanks @KenS I will give these a go.